# Core dump error while hitting localhost:3000

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, mysql2

I'm working with ruby 2.7.5 and rails 6.1.7 on ubuntu 22.04LTS. I've cloned my project and bundle it. Everything is working fine but when I start server by rails s and hit url (localhost:3000), server crashed and error says coredump.

```
Processing by Users::SettingsController#basic as HTML
/home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/mysql2-0.5.4/lib/mysql2/client.rb:95: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x0000000000000000
ruby 2.7.5p203 (2021-11-24 revision f69aeb8314) [x86_64-linux]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0138 p:---- s:1057 e:001056 CFUNC  :connect
c:0137 p:0623 s:1045 e:001044 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/mysql2-0.5.4/lib/mysql2/client.rb:95 [FINISH]
c:0136 p:---- s:1030 e:001029 CFUNC  :new
c:0135 p:0017 s:1025 e:001024 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:40
c:0134 p:0118 s:1019 e:001017 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:23 [FINISH]
c:0133 p:---- s:1013 e:001012 CFUNC  :public_send
c:0132 p:0021 s:1007 e:001006 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb
c:0131 p:0021 s:1003 e:001002 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb
c:0130 p:0014 s:0999 e:000998 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb
c:0129 p:0012 s:0993 e:000992 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb
c:0128 p:0011 s:0987 e:000985 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb
c:0127 p:0021 s:0981 e:000977 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb
c:0126 p:0299 s:0974 e:000973 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb
c:0125 p:0014 s:0964 e:000963 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:327
c:0124 p:0003 s:0960 e:000959 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:283
c:0123 p:0053 s:0956 e:000955 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:553
c:0122 p:0004 s:0951 e:000950 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/attributes.rb:250
c:0121 p:0020 s:0947 e:000946 BLOCK  /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:539 [FINISH]
c:0120 p:---- s:0944 e:000943 CFUNC  :synchronize
c:0119 p:0013 s:0940 e:000939 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:536
c:0118 p:0003 s:0936 e:000935 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:402
c:0117 p:0003 s:0932 e:000931 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:187
c:0116 p:0057 s:0927 e:000926 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:57
c:0115 p:0017 s:0919 e:000918 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/meetingking/gems/paracas_core/app/models/ability.rb:5 [FINISH]
c:0114 p:---- s:0914 e:000913 CFUNC  :new
c:0113 p:0031 s:0909 e:000908 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/cancancan-3.4.0/lib/cancan/controller_additions.rb:354
c:0112 p:0008 s:0905 e:000904 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/cancancan-3.4.0/lib/cancan/controller_additions.rb:339
c:0111 p:0007 s:0900 e:000899 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/meetingking/paracas_account_manager/app/controllers/users/settings_controller.rb:7
c:0110 p:0010 s:0896 e:000895 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/actionpack-6.1.7/lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6
c:0109 p:0009 s:0890 e:000889 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/actionpack-6.1.7/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:228
c:0108 p:0024 s:0884 e:000883 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/actionpack-6.1.7/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30
c:0107 p:0009 s:0879 e:000878 BLOCK  /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/actionpack-6.1.7/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42
c:0106 p:0048 s:0876 e:000874 BLOCK  /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117
c:0105 p:0013 s:0866 e:000865 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/actiontext-6.1.7/lib/action_text/rendering.rb:20
c:0104 p:0021 s:0860 e:000859 BLOCK  /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/actiontext-6.1.7/lib/action_text/engine.rb:59 [FINISH]
c:0103 p:---- s:0855 e:000854 CFUNC  :instance_exec
c:0102 p:0127 s:0849 e:000848 BLOCK  /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126
c:0101 p:0124 s:0840 E:000488 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:137
c:0100 p:0006 s:0831 E:0009b8 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/actionpack-6.1.7/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41
c:0099 p:0008 s:0826 e:000825 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/actionpack-6.1.7/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22
c:0098 p:0009 s:0820 e:000819 BLOCK  /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/actionpack-6.1.7/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:34
c:0097 p:0010 s:0815 e:000814 BLOCK  /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203
c:0096 p:0022 s:0812 e:000811 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24
c:0095 p:0023 s:0804 e:000803 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203
c:0094 p:0098 s:0798 e:000797 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/actionpack-6.1.7/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:33
c:0093 p:0017 s:0792 e:000791 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/actionpack-6.1.7/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:249
c:0092 p:0026 s:0787 e:000786 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27
c:0091 p:0082 s:0781 e:000780 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/actionpack-6.1.7/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:165
c:0090 p:0062 s:0774 e:000773 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/actionview-6.1.7/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39
c:0089 p:0017 s:0768 e:000767 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/actionpack-6.1.7/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190
c:0088 p:0034 s:0761 e:000760 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/actionpack-6.1.7/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:254
c:0087 p:0010 s:0754 e:000753 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/actionpack-6.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50
c:0086 p:0036 s:0746 e:000745 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/actionpack-6.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33
c:0085 p:0110 s:0738 e:000737 BLOCK  /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/actionpack-6.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50 [FINISH]
c:0084 p:---- s:0725 e:000724 CFUNC  :each
c:0083 p:0008 s:0721 e:000720 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/actionpack-6.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32
c:0082 p:0042 s:0716 e:000715 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/actionpack-6.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:842
c:0081 p:0097 s:0710 e:000709 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.15.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99
c:0080 p:0157 s:0699 e:000698 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/omniauth-2.1.0/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:202
c:0079 p:0007 s:0692 e:000691 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/omniauth-2.1.0/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:169
c:0078 p:0097 s:0687 e:000686 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.15.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99
c:0077 p:0157 s:0676 e:000675 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/omniauth-2.1.0/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:202
c:0076 p:0007 s:0669 e:000668 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/omniauth-2.1.0/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:169
c:0075 p:0097 s:0664 e:000663 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.15.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99
c:0074 p:0007 s:0653 e:000652 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/omniauth-2.1.0/lib/omniauth/builder.rb:44
c:0073 p:0097 s:0648 e:000647 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.15.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99
c:0072 p:0007 s:0637 e:000636 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.15.0/lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:30
c:0071 p:0088 s:0632 e:000631 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.15.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99
c:0070 p:0007 s:0621 e:000620 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.15.0/lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:38
c:0069 p:0088 s:0609 e:000608 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.15.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99
c:0068 p:0017 s:0598 e:000597 BLOCK  /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/warden-1.2.9/lib/warden/manager.rb:36 [FINISH]
c:0067 p:---- s:0595 e:000594 CFUNC  :catch
c:0066 p:0057 s:0590 e:000589 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/warden-1.2.9/lib/warden/manager.rb:34
c:0065 p:0097 s:0584 e:000583 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.15.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99
c:0064 p:0035 s:0573 e:000572 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/rack-2.2.5/lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15
c:0063 p:0097 s:0564 e:000563 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.15.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99
c:0062 p:0007 s:0553 e:000552 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/rack-2.2.5/lib/rack/etag.rb:27
c:0061 p:0097 s:0542 e:000541 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.15.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99
c:0060 p:0048 s:0531 e:000530 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/rack-2.2.5/lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:27
c:0059 p:0097 s:0522 e:000521 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.15.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99
c:0058 p:0007 s:0511 e:000510 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/rack-2.2.5/lib/rack/head.rb:12
c:0057 p:0097 s:0503 e:000502 METHOD /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/newrelic_rpm-5000 r--p 00009000 103:03 11694676                  /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/json-1.8.6/lib/json/ext/generator.so
7fa3f2a55000-7fa3f2a56000 rw-p 0000a000 103:03 11694676                  /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/json-1.8.6/lib/json/ext/generator.so
7fa3f2a56000-7fa3f2a5a000 r--p 00000000 103:03 278285                    /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/date_core.so
7fa3f2a5a000-7fa3f2a8a000 r-xp 00004000 103:03 278285                    /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/date_core.so
7fa3f2a8a000-7fa3f2a93000 r--p 00034000 103:03 278285                    /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/date_core.so
7fa3f2a93000-7fa3f2a94000 r--p 0003c000 103:03 278285                    /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/date_core.so
7fa3f2a94000-7fa3f2a95000 rw-p 0003d000 103:03 278285                    /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/date_core.so
7fa3f2a95000-7fa3f2a96000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa3f2a96000-7fa3f2aac000 r--p 00000000 103:03 11291857                  /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0
7fa3f2aac000-7fa3f2aeb000 r-xp 00016000 103:03 11291857                  /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0
7fa3f2aeb000-7fa3f2afd000 r--p 00055000 103:03 11291857                  /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0
7fa3f2afd000-7fa3f2b01000 r--p 00066000 103:03 11291857                  /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0
7fa3f2b01000-7fa3f2b08000 rw-p 0006a000 103:03 11291857                  /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0
7fa3f2b09000-7fa3f2b0b000 r--p 00000000 103:03 11701188                  /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/ruby-ll-2.1.2/lib/libll.so
7fa3f2b0b000-7fa3f2b0d000 r-xp 00002000 103:03 11701188                  /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/ruby-ll-2.1.2/lib/libll.so
7fa3f2b0d000-7fa3f2b0e000 r--p 00004000 103:03 11701188                  /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/ruby-ll-2.1.2/lib/libll.so
7fa3f2b0e000-7fa3f2b0f000 r--p 00004000 103:03 11701188                  /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/ruby-ll-2.1.2/lib/libll.so
7fa3f2b0f000-7fa3f2b10000 rw-p 00005000 103:03 11701188                  /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/ruby-ll-2.1.2/lib/libll.so
7fa3f2b10000-7fa3f2b11000 r--p 00000000 103:03 278218                    /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/enc/iso_8859_1.so
7fa3f2b11000-7fa3f2b12000 r-xp 00001000 103:03 278218                    /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/enc/iso_8859_1.so
7fa3f2b12000-7fa3f2b13000 r--p 00002000 103:03 278218                    /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/enc/iso_8859_1.so
7fa3f2b13000-7fa3f2b14000 r--p 00002000 103:03 278218                    /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/enc/iso_8859_1.so
7fa3f2b14000-7fa3f2b15000 rw-p 00003000 103:03 278218                    /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/enc/iso_8859_1.so
7fa3f2b15000-7fa3f2b17000 r--p 00000000 103:03 9444809                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.8.1.0
7fa3f2b17000-7fa3f2b1e000 r-xp 00002000 103:03 9444809                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.8.1.0
7fa3f2b1e000-7fa3f2b1f000 r--p 00009000 103:03 9444809                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.8.1.0
7fa3f2b1f000-7fa3f2b20000 ---p 0000a000 103:03 9444809                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.8.1.0
7fa3f2b20000-7fa3f2b21000 r--p 0000a000 103:03 9444809                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.8.1.0
7fa3f2b21000-7fa3f2b22000 rw-p 0000b000 103:03 9444809                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.8.1.0
7fa3f2b22000-7fa3f2b25000 r--p 00000000 103:03 9444964                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fa3f2b25000-7fa3f2b3c000 r-xp 00003000 103:03 9444964                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fa3f2b3c000-7fa3f2b40000 r--p 0001a000 103:03 9444964                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fa3f2b40000-7fa3f2b41000 r--p 0001d000 103:03 9444964                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fa3f2b41000-7fa3f2b42000 rw-p 0001e000 103:03 9444964                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fa3f2b42000-7fa3f2b45000 r--p 00000000 103:03 9445532                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2
7fa3f2b45000-7fa3f2b4f000 r-xp 00003000 103:03 9445532                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2
7fa3f2b4f000-7fa3f2b52000 r--p 0000d000 103:03 9445532                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2
7fa3f2b52000-7fa3f2b53000 r--p 0000f000 103:03 9445532                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2
7fa3f2b53000-7fa3f2b54000 rw-p 00010000 103:03 9445532                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2
7fa3f2b54000-7fa3f2b56000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
.....................
.......................
7fa3f2b59000-7fa3f2b5a000 r--p 00000000 103:03 278226                    /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/enc/windows_31j.so
7fa3f2b5a000-7fa3f2b5b000 r-xp 00001000 103:03 278226                    /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/enc/windows_31j.so
7fa3f2b5b000-7fa3f2b5c000 r--p 00002000 103:03 278226                    /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/enc/windows_31j.so
7fa3f2b5c000-7fa3f2b5d000 ---p 00003000 103:03 278226                    /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/enc/windows_31j.so
7fa3f2b5d000-7fa3f2b5e000 r--p 00003000 103:03 278226                    /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/enc/windows_31j.so
7fa3f2b5e000-7fa3f2b5f000 rw-p 00004000 103:03 278226                    /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/enc/windows_31j.so
7fa3f2b5f000-7fa3f2b60000 r--p 00000000 103:03 278250                    /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/enc/trans/utf_16_32.so
7fa3f2b60000-7fa3f2b61000 r-xp 00001000 103:03 278250                    /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/enc/trans/utf_16_32.so
7fa3f2b61000-7fa3f2b62000 r--p 00002000 103:03 278250                    /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/enc/trans/utf_16_32.so
7fa3f2b62000-7fa3f2b63000 ---p 00003000 103:03 278250                    /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/enc/trans/utf_16_32.so
7fa3f2b63000-7fa3f2b64000 r--p 00003000 103:03 278250                    /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/enc/trans/utf_16_32.so
7fa3f2b64000-7fa3f2b65000 rw-p 00004000 103:03 278250                    /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/enc/trans/utf_16_32.so
7fa3f2b65000-7fa3f2b6b000 r--p 00000000 103:03 11696052                  /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/mysql2-0.5.4/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so
7fa3f2b6b000-7fa3f2b75000 r-xp 00006000 103:03 11696052                  /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/mysql2-0.5.4/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so
7fa3f2b75000-7fa3f2b78000 r--p 00010000 103:03 11696052                  /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/mysql2-0.5.4/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so
7fa3f2b78000-7fa3f2b7a000 r--p 00012000 103:03 11696052                  /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/mysql2-0.5.4/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so
7fa3f2b7a000-7fa3f2b7b000 rw-p 00014000 103:03 11696052                  /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/mysql2-0.5.4/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so
7fa3f2b7b000-7fa3f2b7e000 r--p 00000000 103:03 278200                    /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/zlib.so
7fa3f2b7e000-7fa3f2b88000 r-xp 00003000 103:03 278200                    /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/zlib.so
7fa3f2b88000-7fa3f2b8b000 r--p 0000d000 103:03 278200                    /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/zlib.so
7fa3f2b8b000-7fa3f2b8c000 ---p 00010000 103:03 278200                    /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/zlib.so
7fa3f2b8c000-7fa3f2b8d000 r--p 00010000 103:03 278200                    /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/zlib.so
/home/faheemqazi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/enc/trans/transdb.so
7fa3f79e4000-7fa3f79e5000 r--p 00000000 103:03 278240                    /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/enc/encdb.so
7fa3f79e5000-7fa3f79e6000 r-xp 00001000 103:03 278240                    /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/enc/encdb.so
7fa3f79e6000-7fa3f79e7000 r--p 00002000 103:03 278240                    /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/enc/encdb.so
7fa3f79e7000-7fa3f79e8000 r--p 00002000 103:03 278240                    /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/enc/encdb.so
7fa3f79e8000-7fa3f79e9000 rw-p 00003000 103:03 278240                    /home/faheemqazi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/enc/encdb.so
7fa3f79e9000-7fa3f79eb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa3f79eb000-7fa3f79ed000 r--p 00000000 103:03 9444236                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
7fa3f79ed000-7fa3f7a17000 r-xp 00002000 103:03 9444236                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
7fa3f7a17000-7fa3f7a22000 r--p 0002c000 103:03 9444236                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
7fa3f7a22000-7fa3f7a23000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa3f7a23000-7fa3f7a25000 r--p 00037000 103:03 9444236                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
7fa3f7a25000-7fa3f7a27000 rw-p 00039000 103:03 9444236                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
7fff9e05d000-7fff9e85c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff9e93d000-7fff9e941000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7fff9e941000-7fff9e943000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 --xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]


Aborted (core dumped)
```

I've tried resinstalling ruby but nothing happen. I've created a new project to test ruby. I findout that ruby is working fine. The issue is in mysql because when I use mysql db it gives core dump error in every project wheter it's new or existing. More over when I run Rails db:create comand it gives same error (core dumped).

Comment: I'm sorry, but tgis is not something we can help you with, you need to raise the issue with either mysql ir whoever creayed the ruby mysql driver

Comment: Try upgrading from v0.5.4 to v.0.5.5
https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/releases/tag/0.5.5
Other users are reporting openssl issues, which may be fixed in 0.5.5
https://github.com/huginn/huginn/issues/3149